# Getting a static instance of a class (singleton) by using getDefinitionByName 

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop, singleton

I have a `ManagerClass` with a Singleton implementation inside, I get the instance by calling `ManagerClass.getInstance()`.

Can I get that same instance by just having the class name as a string? 
I have tried something like:

```
var theInstance:* = getDefinitionByName("ManagerClass").getInstance as Class;
theInstance.doTrace(); // I get a 1009 error here
```

Comment: I am not sure why you would every want to do it that way. It is a very natural thing to use getInstance() with a singleton it is setup like that for a reason. Is there some reason your wanting to go outside the box with this? why not just do it the normal way?

Comment: because i need to have reference to multiple singletons - and need to be able to pass the classes name in instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: did you forget parenthesis () at getInstance() ?

Comment: Wait, what? You need to 'pass the class names' instead of hardcoding it? Are you creating dynamic singletons?  I think you're trying to find a solution to a problem that doesn't exist.  What are you trying to solve by doing this? What's the point?  It should also be mentioned that using the singleton pattern is frown upon in a Flex application.

Comment: You're indeed missing a n() and `as Class` should be removed.
@J_A_X about the singleton frown upon, why so?

Comment: @Kodiak Singletons are an anti-pattern and a maintenance nightmare.  First and foremost, it's impossible to stop people from instantiating it because actionscript doesn't have private constructors, so if you have a Singleton, I could still do 'new Singleton()' and it will still work unless you throw an error in the constructor which would then only be caught on runtime.  A better alternative is to use dependency injection (used in many application frameworks like Parsley and Robotlegs) which makes your application easy to manage and more malleable if you were to change your mind.

Comment: @J_A_X Wikipedia tought be a bit of depency injection and I don't quite understand how you could replace a singleton in cases like `ServiceManager.getInstance().callService("myservice")` or `Model.getInstance().myData` with this design. There, Singletons are used to replace some kind of global static variables or methods containers (which they are). If you have a little time to tell me more, or if your have links to some resources about the subject, I'd be glad!

Answer (score 1):

well - im dealing with singletons because the application that I'm working on is written in cairngorm, and a whole bunch of things have to be singletons in it. 
in regards to why I need to "pass the class names" instead of hardcoding them - is for exact that reason - I don't want to hardcode anything in. this application is 5 years in developement, and now would not be good time to switch it to RobotLegs and such.

haha - yea, you're right - i forgot the () after getInstance. Must be the lack of sleep... Now it works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure why not make a Singleton manager (similar to the Flex core mx.core.Singleton class) that registers these classes and handles if they're null.

Similar to here :

http://segfaultlabs.com/devlogs/overriding-default-flexair-mxmanagers-implementations